# 2 out of 3 events rule in gst

Tags: income-tax, india, hst, gst

Why in India when rate of tax changes during supply 2 out of 3 events rule applies that is when 2 out of 3 things,  ( provision of goods,receipt of payment,issue of invoice) occurs then that date is considered to be time of supply however why not only 1 out of 3 events rule applies ?